# XAML Designer not loading WinRT Toolkit for windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm trying to use the WinRT Toolkit for wp 8.1 in my project. I installed the package from nuget and have written this snippet in the main grid.The Emulator works just fine. but The XAML Designer is not loading the control, what do I need to do?

```
<faysal:CascadingTextBlock 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="fafdsda"
        FontSize="35"
        />
```

[image: XAML designer shows this!]

the namespace in the xaml is like below

```
xmlns:faysal="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRT XAML Toolkit doesn't have good support for design view unfortunately. `CascadingTextBlock` is one of the controls that simply doesn't show up in the designer.

Comment: Just a note though - while design view isn't supported explicitly - you can use the visual tree debugger to see how your property adjustments affect the UI in the actually running application. This is actually more reliable than the design view. You'd want to NuGet-install WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging.Windows and call WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging.DC.ShowVisualTree(this); in your page to invoke it and then press Ctrl+Shift to select a control and adjust the parameters in the properties pane.

Comment: Thanks again, i'd definitely use it for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

To install WinRT XAML Toolkit - Data Visualization Controls, run the following command in the Package Manager Console
Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization 
then xmlns:faysal="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"